# Launch Flow from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, visual-workflow

I'm trying to launch flow from lightning component + putting this lightning component inside my record page, so it will fired when the page is loaded.

I set everything as needed, but it seems that the variable is not been passed to the flow .. Can someone please help me and check if i'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks !

My Component:

```
 <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
</aura:component>
```

My controller:

```
({
init : function (component) {

    console.log('inside controller');

    // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
    var flow = component.find("flowData");

    var inputVariables = [
               {
                    name : "CaseId", 
                    type : "String", 
                    value: component.get("v.recordId")
               }
        ];

    // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
    flow.startFlow("Testing_Flow", inputVariables);
}
```

})

Comment: is there a reason you are not using the standard flow component?  it is aware of the record ID and would load on page load.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be inside the flow you're calling. Make sure you have a Variable resource of type Text with name CaseId and with the Input checkbox checked.